# How can I round value to 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
SELECT
       CONCAT((COUNT_PEOPLE_INSIDE_3MILES/ COUNT_TOTAL_PEOPLE*100),'%') Percentage_People_Within_3miles
FROM
 
(
  
SELECT count(*) COUNT_PEOPLE_INSIDE_3MILES
  FROM CLIENT_DATA
  WHERE (ABS(C_ADD_X) >=1 AND ABS(C_ADD_X) <=3) AND (ABS(C_ADD_Y) >=1 AND ABS(C_ADD_Y) <=3)

),

(

  SELECT count(CLIENT_ID) COUNT_TOTAL_PEOPLE
  FROM CLIENT_DATA

);
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROUND() function in MySQL To round to 2 decimal.

```
SELECT ROUND(your_value, 2);
```

Comment: Did you notice that the question is tagged "oracle" (and **not** "mysql") ?

Comment: Nevertheless, this answer works for Oracle also. And for most of modern DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ROUND(your_value, 2);
This can be done